# Removal Background with Shadows on HUE

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image of a leaf on a poorly white screen and need to find out just the leaf:

[image: Leaf Image]

The problem is that it contains greenish shadows, so simple color-based methods are not enough. Thus, I need some preprocessing to achieve an uniform background and to enhance important features. The goal is to delete undesired noise and distortions to apply an Expectation Maximization algorithm.

[image: HSV Image Channels]

I tried playing with OpenCV fastNlMeansDenoising, but it is not sufficient.

**UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION**

When segmenting with color it is imperative to use the right color domains that exclude undesired noise. So we used Saturation and Value color components for leaf segmentation. This was useful for posterior segmentation using Expectation-Maximization (EM). I used OpenCV to convert the original images into the HSV domain. Then, using NumPy, I extracted the Saturation and Value components, which were fed to the EM algorithm.

Once images were converted to HSV and the desired channels were extracted, I applied EM to the color domain in order to cluster the pixels into one of 2 possible groups: leaf and non-leaf groups. However, due to that greenish the EM is returning a wrong result.

Comment: Most of the shadow is probably just antialiasing. Maybe you can just apply an [erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)) to the mask?

Comment: I tried it @MarkRansom, but it still not good =/

Comment: Did you try `grabcut` ? how many images like that do you have and will they always have a clean white border?

Comment: I believe you posted this problem befor and like the last time I don't understand your problem. The leaf is surrounded by white. So why do you have problems getting the leaf only? This should be super easy. Why not simply use the V-channel? why do the shadows matter?

Comment: What is `greenish shadows`, my English is poor, can you highlight? And If you want to remove the noise on the border of the HUE, then the `mask-op` is enough. https://i.stack.imgur.com/013ns.jpg

Comment: @user1767754 I have 7 images like that, and they will always have a clean white background

Comment: @Piglet I need to preprocessing the image to be able to use Expectation Maximization for segmentation, which is trained by using the S and V of the HSV domain. However, due to that greenish shadows, it is segmenting wrong

Comment: @Silencer how did you achieve that? In the Hue Channel, you can see some gray pixels around the leaf

Comment: then why don't you add a preprocessing step that removes the artifacts in the Hue channel using the information from the V channel?

Comment: @Piglet I'm trying to find a way to do it, but until now no success